# Return Error.jsp or Input.jsp AJAX?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I do an AJAX call through which I call my Action class which returns either an Error.jsp or Input.jsp.

**struts.xml**:

```
<action name="updateThresholdParameters"
            class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction" method="updateThresholdParameters">
<result name="display">pages/Input.jsp</result>
<result name="error">pages/Error.jsp</result>
```

In my JavaScript file I get either of JSP in my `data` :

**JS**:

```
success: function(data){
    if(){ //success
        alert('Updated DB');
    }else
        $('#ErrorDiv').html(data);
    }
```

How should I differntiate which JSP is getting returned??

Answer (score 0):

Based on the contents of the two .jsps. You cannot (nor should you) know on the client side the name of the .jsp file being included.

Typical use case is that you have XML or JSON in those JSPs, and they have different contents that you can query for.

Comment: Can you tell how to check contents of two jsp's returned? I get html page in 'data', how should i search in that html?

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha that would depend on the JSP content and HTTP status codes. Include them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There may be different ways.

1 you can use two different div one for input one for error page

2 bases on content you can identify the page type like adding a html commet on both pages that while displaying using ajax read and check the content